# Using MySQL alias name with case statement after then

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, alias

I can't use MySQL alias name with CASE statement, it give syntax error as following:

```
SELECT IFNULL(min(mFR.date),'') AS `firstDate`,
    CASE `data` 
        WHEN 'Sales'         THEN IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) AS `sales`
        WHEN 'Return'        THEN IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) AS `return`
        WHEN 'Receiving In'  THEN IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) AS `receiving_in`
        WHEN 'Receiving Out' THEN IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) AS `receiving_out`
        WHEN 'Stock'         THEN IFNULL(SUM(qty),0) AS `stock`
    END
FROM  `full_report`
```

It gives me (syntax error near [AS `sales`]).

Any suggestions?

Comment: The alias will be for the whole case, not each branch

Comment: @GurV is there's any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use alias for each branch of the case, which is not possible.

I think you want to use separate case:

```
SELECT IFNULL(min(mFR.date),'') AS `firstDate`
    ,sum(CASE `data` WHEN 'Sales'         THEN qty END) AS `sales`
    ,sum(CASE `data` WHEN 'Return'        THEN qty END) AS `return`
    ,sum(CASE `data` WHEN 'Receiving In'  THEN qty END) AS `receiving_in`
    ,sum(CASE `data` WHEN 'Receiving Out' THEN qty END) AS `receiving_out`
    ,sum(CASE `data` WHEN 'Stock'         THEN qty END) AS `stock`
FROM  `full_report`
```

Comment: Just to put commas after each case ;)